# Image on bootstrap carousel won't stretch

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I know this issue seems recurrent, but I've searched through many posts on how to really stretch my image to the full width of it's parent element, but none of them seemed to work.

So, I have a carousel and I want all the images to display at full width. The strange thing is every image appears filling the whole space at the animation of transition time, but it shrinks as soon as the animation ends.

Padding 0 didn't work. Width 100% didn't work. col-12 didn't work. The only thing that works is setting width to a fixed value, but that kills responsiveness.

```
<div class="position-fixed">
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active" data-interval="5000">
                <img src="media/imagens/home1.png" class="d-block w-100" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="5000">
                <img src="media/imagens/home2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="5000">
                <img src="media/imagens/home3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="5000">
                <img src="media/imagens/home4.jpg" class="d-block w-100" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="5000">
                <img src="media/imagens/home5.png" class="d-block w-100" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post your css too? Thanks.

Comment: I'm currently not using any css, just bootstrap default styling.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a class of “row” to the outer div so it would be:

```
<div class="row position-fixed">
```

Comment: It didn't work. I think it could be something about me resizing the image because it really has 100% width but only during animation time...but I've attempted to change basically all the fields and it didn't work